# CSS "top" property not working with percentage (%), but working with pixels (px)

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  background: #8E2800;
}
#main {
  background: purple;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}
#title {
  background: grey;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 40%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="title">
      <h2>Weather Forecast</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also as working demo can be found on codepen:
http://codepen.io/manzur/pen/RomyjK?editors=1100

Comment: `top` is relative to the parent, and if you specify a percentage, it's the percentage of the height of the parent. But the parent doesn't have an (explicit) height, so that won't work. I'd be happy to provide an answer (maybe using `vw` or a similar unit), but it's not clear to me what exactly you want to happen.

Comment: What do you mean *not working?* What's the difference between what you expected and what you get?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm trying to center the #title div. As per your answer, I set the parent div height to some px, and then it worked, it centered wrt to the height of parent div. But I don't want to set a specific height to the parent div and want to center #title div

Comment: Well, if the parent `main` does not have a height, how should its children know how to center themselves?

Comment: The parent container should also has haight

Answer (score 7):

`position: absolute` positions with respect to the edges of the nearest positioned ancestor.

`#main` has `position: relative` so it is the element that `#title` is positioned with respect to.

`#main` has no content which is in normal flow (the only content is absolutely positioned) and it has a `height` of `auto` (the default). The computed height is therefore `0`.

`50%` of `0` is `0`.

You need to either position with respect to something else (e.g. the viewport by removing `position: relative` from `#main`) or give `#main` some height (by adding content or using the `height` property).